# jCarousel (v0.3.0), Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'index' of null jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

My home page has one carousel. but when clicking to menu links this time only carousel photos change and autostart circular slide must begin. all ok but some times google chrome giving console error. and not begin autostart carousel and sometimes stop to last item. i want when click to menu reloading new carousel data and autostart my circular carousel.

jcarousel version: v0.3.0 - 2013-11-22
jquery version: 1.10.1.min

**before `</head>` tag my code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jcarousel = $('.jcarousel');
    jcarousel.jcarousel({
        wrap:'circular',
        animation:{duration:1500,easing:'easeInOutExpo'}
    })
    .jcarouselAutoscroll({interval:2000});

    $('.prev').jcarouselControl({target: '-=1'});
    $('.next').jcarouselControl({target: '+=1'});
});
```

**After carousel** coming my menu script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".depth0").delegate('a','click',function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("rel");
        if(id){
            $.get("/jcarousel.php?carousel="+id,function(data){
                $('.jcarousel').html(data).jcarousel('reload',{wrap:'circular',animation:{duration:1500,easing:'easeInOutExpo'}}).jcarouselAutoscroll({interval:2000,autostart:true});
            });
        }
    });
});
```

chrome console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'index' of null jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
$.jCarousel.plugin.prepare jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
$.jCarousel.plugin.reload jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
$.jCarousel.plugin._create jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
create jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
$.(anonymous function) jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
(anonymous function) jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
x.extend.each jquery.min.js:4
x.fn.x.each jquery.min.js:4
$.fn.(anonymous function) jquery.jcarousel.min.js:1
(anonymous function) (index):37
c jquery.min.js:4
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:4
x.extend.ready jquery.min.js:4
q
```

MY PROBLEMS:

1) Carousel `wrap:'circular'` not working. Stops the carousel.

2) Sometimes carousel autostarts but stops at last item.

3) Sometimes Chrome console gives index error.

Thanks for helping.

Sorry my English is not good.

Comment: If you can somehow come up with an example that shows the error in a fiddle that would help.  Something like http://jsfiddle.net/Znztg/ I know this is an older version of jcarousel but you could look into loading your version and demonstrating the error with a fiddle.

Comment: i found my problem. if carousel item not give to width size this time giving error. needed width="" attribute list element. thnx all. ;)